# Tomcat have started on mac m1 , but 8080 port can't be connected

Tags: macos, tomcat, apple-silicon

Although tomcat hava started, locahost:8080 can't be connected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMVTl.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yMey.png)

I hava tried some ways, such as:
1、close port 8080,But 8080 port is not used.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeTFn.png)
2、Configure the path in the .zshrc file，but it's no use.

Comment: Can you add the startup logs to the question (edit the question)? They are in `logs/catalina.<today's date>.log` of the Tomcat installation. Please add those as text, not an image.

Comment: Can I how to do this , I hava found catalina.out in logs file. I am not understand your meaning , please speak careful again.

Comment: I hava solved this problem , thanks . It's jdk version problem .

Answer (score 0):

First use `ps -ef | grep java` command to see whether the Tomcat process exists. If it doesn't exist, check the logs `logs/catalina.out` to find out error messages.
Then make sure whether your Tomcat uses port `8080` to deal with HTTP requests. You can find similar text in the log file:

```
06-Jun-2021 12:58:12.264 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
```

I changed the HTTP port to `8081`, so the log shows `http-nio-8081`. You can view/change the port in file `conf/server.xml`:

```xml
    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: OK,thanks , after 3 minutes , I hava finished this problem , jdk is much too new, I finsh jdk 1.8 , it's successful , amazing.
That's all , the least jdk is not suitable to tomcat .

Comment: @biaozhu Are you sure it's caused by the JDK version? I can run Tomcat 10.0.6 successfully with latest AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9).

Comment: Yes,I am sure that , I have tried almost wat on the Internet , which is no power , however, I change my jdk version , localhost:8080 can connect right now. I am also amazing to this .

Answer (score 0):

The least jdk is not suitable tomcat , we need install jdk1.8 by whitch can solve this problem . It's a amazing day .